# Component not displaying correctly when zoomed out

Tags: html, css, reactjs

When the page is zoomed out then the component gets shrinked. but when the zoom effect is removed that is no zoom effect is applied then the component works perfectly.These are the screenshots.

[Screenshot when zoomed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUGEr.png)

[Screenshot when screen is normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrGgF.png)

Comment: Both screenshots are identical. Is that intentional?

Comment: @NickMcCurdy please check now

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: when the screen is zoomed out the navbar and component below it also gets resized, i checked the media queries and all but nothing seems to work. @NickMcCurdy

Comment: Please post some code that reproduces the issue.